# Change CPT 'Add New Post' to CPT Name

Tags: wordpress

How do I change the 'Add New Post' to reflect the name of my custom post type? Do I add something to the following code. I know it can be done...

```
function create_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'venues',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Venues' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Venue' )
      ),
  );
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yq9VW.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the labels array add:

```
'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'venue', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Venue', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ),
```

Also read the WordPress codex:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Answer (score 0):

You can use the code below to get the result expected.

```
<?php 

        $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Venues', 'Post Type General Name', 'text-domain' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Venue', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'text-domain' ),
        'menu_name'           => esc_html__( 'Venues', 'text-domain' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => esc_html__( 'Parent Venues', 'text-domain' ),
        'all_items'           => esc_html__( 'All Venues', 'text-domain' ),
        'view_item'           => esc_html__( 'View Venues', 'text-domain' ),
        'add_new_item'        => esc_html__( 'Add New Venues', 'text-domain' ),
        'add_new'             => esc_html__( 'Add New', 'text-domain' ),
        'edit_item'           => esc_html__( 'Edit Venues', 'text-domain' ),
        'update_item'         => esc_html__( 'Update Venues', 'text-domain' ),
        'search_items'        => esc_html__( 'Search Venues', 'text-domain' ),
        'not_found'           => esc_html__( 'Not Found', 'text-domain' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => esc_html__( 'Not found in Trash', 'text-domain' ),
    );

// Set other options for Custom Post Type

    $args = array(
        'label'               => esc_html__( 'venues', 'text-domain' ),
        'description'         => esc_html__( 'Venues news and reviews', 'text-domain' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        // Features this CPT supports in Post Editor
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),
        // You can associate this CPT with a taxonomy or custom taxonomy. 
        'taxonomies'          => array( 'main_product_category' ),

        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
    );


    register_post_type( 'venues', $args );
```

Hope this will help.